# How to include functions and categories in new XCode projects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have created categories of NSBezierPath, functions that deals with geometric objects, and classes that use aforementioned code.

What is the most natural way to use include them in new projects? I'm using them in almost all of my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a framework of it and use the framework in your project.

This is the most sensible option, IMO, if those classes provide a coherent set of features. Otherwise, you could create a set of frameworks; in this case, though, beware of dependencies among them, because it would make managing them more complex and maybe the effort of it would not give any advantage.

If you really want to go 'pro' you might think of creating your own Xcode template to include those frameworks by default in your projects. Have a look at [this post](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/) about making Xcode templates.

Comment: All the functions are closely related. They all deal with geometry, and I frequently use the low level functions I created for the geometric kernel, and the high level layer (using the kernel), depending on the situation.

Comment: I would say: it depends on how you see the kernel: do you think you might use it by itself, maybe in another independent framework you might devise? if yes, make the kernel a separate framework; otherwise, just one framework including everything could be the right choice; In the sake of simplicity, I would go for one framework that you can always refactor in 2 different ones in case need arise.